# Julia: Error passing user-defined struct to functions

Tags: julia

I have these structures defined as:

```
struct CLocation{T<:Real}
  x::Array{T,1}
  y::Array{T,1}
  z::Array{T,1}
end

struct CSize{T<:Real}
  x::Array{T,1}
  y::Array{T,1}
  z::Array{T,1}
end

struct FLocation{T<:Real}
  x::Array{T,1}
  y::Array{T,1}
  z::Array{T,1}
end

struct MStructure
  dimension::Real
  dims::Array{Int,1}
  csize::CSize
  ccenters::CLocation
  fcenters::FLocation
  corner::Array{Int,1}
  edge::Array{Int,1}
end

struct CValue # {T<:Real}
  domain::MStructure
  value::Union{Array{<:Real}, DenseArray{Bool}} #Union{Array{T}, BitArray{}}
end
```

Where the `CValue.value` entry stores the numerical values of interest to me.

I have 3 variables that use this type, that are defined as:

```
c_new = Vector{CValue}(undef,N)
x_new = Vector{CValue}(undef,N)
c_tot::CValue
```

Where `c_tot` is simply of type `CValue`, and `c_new` and `x_new` are vectors of size `N` with each entry of the vector being type `CValue`.

I'd like to pass these variables through 2 operations that I hope to convert to functions:

```
x_new = [c_new[i]/c_tot for i in 1:N]
```

My intention is that this function divides every numerical value in `c_new[i].value` by the corresponding value in `c_tot.value`, giving a vector `x_new` of size N.

and

```
c_tot = [c_tot + c_new[i] for i in 1:N]
```

Which I would like to sum all the values for every c_new[i].value, giving a variable c_tot of type `CValue`

The error I have received is:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching /(::CValue, ::Vector{CValue})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define operations on custom types that you create. Here I think you'd need to define something like

```
Base.:/(a::CValue, b::CValue) = a.value / b.value
```

(Note that it's easier to help you if you can provide copy-pastable code that reproduces the error.)